# What does this code do? assign a= (b==c)

Tags: verilog

I was going through Verilog code, and I came across this:

```
assign a= (b==c);
```

What does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"==" is logical equality operator. Result of (b == c) will be 1 if 'b' is equal to 'c' and will be 0 if not. That result will be assigned to wire a.